# Sending arguments to BLL when using Web Forms Model Binding and FileUpload in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I have an ASP.NET GridView which uses model binding:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="teamMembersGrid"
...
ItemType="Models.TeamMember"
OnCallingDataMethods="teamMembersGrid_CallingDataMethods">
```

I also have a BLL which defines methods for UpdateTeamMember, InsertTeamMember, etc.

One of the columns of the grid displays an image. In edit mode, I need to upload a new image for this column using a FileUpload control. I want to pass this control to the BLL method UpdateTeamMember as a parameter. The problem is: how?

I added in my page, outside the grid, a FileUpload control with ID "FileUpload". It has style="display:none" (I tried to remove this style but it doesn't help). Then, at RowUpdating, I set a value for this control:

```
protected void teamMembersGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   FileUpload = teamMembersGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("FileUpload") as FileUpload;
}
```

In this method, the FileUpload control is retrieved correctly and it has the required information.

And in the BLL, I have this:

```
public void UpdateTeamMember(int teamMemberID, ModelMethodContext context, [Control("FileUpload")] FileUpload fileUpload)
{
...
}
```

In this method of the BLL, the fileUpload parameter is not null, but does not have any file uploaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

hi I got the solution using same webforms modelbinding.
In the formview where you are in insertmode
add this in aspx in the **formview tag** here in this snippet it is

> addCustomer

```
OnItemInserting="addCustomer_ItemInserting"
```

then in the aspx.cs codebehind

```
 protected  void  addCustomer_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {

            FileUpload Fileupload = (FileUpload)addCustomer.FindControl("CustomerImage");

            byte[] covertedByteArr  = // convert stream to bytes here ConvertStreamToBytes(Fileupload.PostedFile.InputStream);
            e.Values["CustomerImage"] = covertedByteArr;
        }
```

CustomerImage is the name of the field in the model which should be of type byte[] .
then on InsertMethod in the BL Layer, you will see that the byte[] is filled properly